# Linq to SQL to append multiple records with a delimiter

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

Sorry for the bad title of the question apologies if it's a duplicate.

I have two db tables:

```
Users                 Documents
-------               --------- 
ID                    ID
Name                  DocumentName
                      UserID
```

Say I have 1 record in `Users`

```
1, "bob"
```

and three related records in `Documents`

```
1, "Doc1", 1
2, "Doc2", 1
3, "Doc3", 1
```

I want to generate a result set:

```
1, "bob", "Doc1, Doc2, Doc3"
```

I've tried various things involving merging of multiple result sets but get the error: `Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator.`

How should I go about doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either:

- take the column "as is" from the server and do the concat in C#
- write an SP that does it, and call the SP via LINQ

The SP (accepting @UserID) can do this like so:

```
DECLARE @txt varchar(max)
SET @txt = ''
SELECT @txt = @txt + [DocumentName] + ', '
FROM [Documents]
WHERE [UserID] = @UserID

SELECT [ID], [Name], @txt AS [Docs]
FROM [Users]
WHERE [ID] = @UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

if youre using raw sql then you can use STUFF and FOR XML PATH syntax, as described in:
[How Stuff and 'For Xml Path' work in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server)
other solution, you need first get data from sql by linq, then make result .AsEnumerable() - now you can use string.Join function

Comment: Please add relevant parts from your link here