# LinqToSql - Prevent sub queries when limiting number of rows returned

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq-to-sql

```
Dim query = (From p in Parent _
            select _
                p.ID, _
                Tags = String.Join("|", p.Child.Select(Function(c) c.Tag.TagName).ToArray)).Take(100)
```

In the above query, when using Take to limit the rows returned, a separate SQL query is executed for each row to return the 'Tags' field. If I remove Take(100), a single query to sent to Sql Server.

So, how do I limit the number of rows returned, while preventing a new sub query being executed for each row?

Answer (score 2):

**edit2**
When working with nested types, so doing new { r, r.childrenCollection }, LINQ translates this to (SELECT TOP 100 FROM r), deleting the join information. When doing a join by yourself this doesn't happen. So something like:

```
        var thingyWithChilds
            = (from p in dc.RightCategories
               join r in dc.Rights on p.Id equals r.CategoryId
               select new { p.Id, r });

        var bla = thingyWithChilds.Take(100);
```

will not cause the same problem.

*other stuff that might apply*

You're doing ToArray() which causes the query to execute as it isn't a IQueryable. Just do ToArray() after you do Take().

**edit** According to this SO topic: [Is there a LINQ equivalent of string.Join(string, string[])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934635/is-there-a-linq-equivalent-of-string-joinstring-string), it is neither possible to use String.Join if you want to do everything on the server, as there is no SQL command available to do that in TSQL.

Comment: Why does it work without the Take()? If I substitute Take with ToList() to execute the query, only one SQL query is generated!

Comment: Because Take is an additional action that has to be performed on the SQL server. query-thats-already-partial-executed.ToList().Take(100), will generate 1 query; query-thats-already-partial-executed.Take(100).ToList() will generate additional queries.

Comment: Okay, but it still seems that there is no way to solve my original question. Even removing the toArray(eg change to simply p.Child) results in the same behaviour.

Comment: Have you used String.Join in your last test, maybe there is no sufficient translation from String.Join to a SQL function in Linq-SQL

Comment: No, changed to Tags = p.Child

Comment: Thanks for all your effort Jan. The problem with using joins is that it returns a flat list rather than ID plus entity set.

Comment: In my code example you get an object containing the ID and the corresponding entity set, afaik exactly what you got in the original query.

Comment: I dont get that in LinqPad. Group Join works as you describe but has the same multi sql query problem.