# Using a stored procedure in an expression

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I am using this Expression to create my ViewModel from Database Models:

ViewModel.cs:

```
 public class TestViewModel
    {
        public static Expression<Func<TestModel, TestViewModel>> Projection => dbModel => new TestViewModel
        {
            Name = dbModel.Name,
            PropertiesCommaSeparated = string.Join(", ", dbModel.TestProperties.Select(x => x.TestProperty.Value))
        };

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string PropertiesCommaSeparated { get; set; }
    }
```

Since `string.Join("","")`  is not supported in Linq to SQL this fails.

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/934668 I want to use a stored procedure.

Is it possible to execute a stored procedure in an expression like this?

I am using Entity Framework .NET Core 3.1

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you want to do in a `...ViewModel`. ViewModels, DTOs ideally shouldn't have any logic unrelated to views (in your case: DB operations).

With that in mind, I'd fetch values beforehand and map those values inside a static factory method [0]:

```cs
public class TestViewModel
{
    public static TestViewModel FromModel(TestModel model)
    {
        return new TestViewModel
        {
            Name = model.Name,
            PropertiesCommaSeparated = string.Join(", ", model.TestProperties.Select(it => it.TestProperty.Value))
        };
    }


    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PropertiesCommaSeparated { get; set; }
}
```

This means you need to [make sure you fetch `TestProperties` property from the database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager). Assuming `TestProperties` is a navigation property for a 1-to-many relationship, you would write:

```cs
var record = _dbContext.TestModel.Include(e => e.TestProperties).First();
var vm = TestViewModel.FromModel(record)
return View(vm);
```

One disadvantage here (still going off on the mentioned assumption) is if `TestProperty` entity is very large with a lot of columns, you might not want to fetch all columns from the database, but only the `Value`. But from the looks of it, you probably have something like this, so I wouldn't worry too much about it.

```cs
class TestProperty
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

[0]: I could have used a constructor here too, but I think static factory `FromModel` is more expressive of its intent. Both are equally valid approaches.

Comment: Thx for answer. Fetching the data first and process it afterwards is no option for me. I especially want to use it in an expression (Linq to SQL) to execute it on the database.

Comment: Alright. [`string.Join` cannot be expressed with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions), because it implies a join + aggregation which complicates things a lot, and it's reasonable that EF team wants to leave that out. You're better off fetching the data from a view / stored procedure. But that can't be done inside an expression. This might put you in the right path https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping